# COUNT(*) on InnoDB whenever phpMyAdmin loads

Tags: mysql, innodb

It's a known issue that innodb is slow in

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Table
```

Hence I avoided that. But I notice that whenever I login to phpmyadmin, it will automatically execute a `count(*)` for my innodb table with 19k rows, which can take up to a minute to execute. Yet it doesn't initiate such `count(*)` for the other innodb table with 4 million rows.

Another clue, in phpmyadmin, under the Records column, the number of records for the 19k-row table is showing the exact value whereas the 4-million-row table is showing an approx.

I understand innodb table gives an estimation of the row count. But it seems that for smaller table, in this case with 19k rows, phpmyadmin decides to do a `count(*)` instead of just giving an estimation.

Question is, is there a way to stop phpmyadmin from doing such count on my innodb table? It's okay to just give an estimation instead of doing an expensive row count whenever I refresh my phpmyadmin screen.

Comment: Think I found the answer. There is a $cfg['MaxExactCount'] = 20000; in phpmyadmin settings. Only rows more than 20k will give an estimates. My next question is, where do I edit $cfg['MaxExactCount']?

Comment: @Kenny, Simply overwrite the value `20000` with a smaller number, e.g. `300`, save the file, refresh phpmyadmin and you're ready to go.

Answer (score 3):

Edit config.inc.php, and change the setting for [MaxExactCount](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_MaxExactCount).

```
$cfg['MaxExactCount']
    Type:   integer
    Default value:  500000

For InnoDB tables, determines for how large tables phpMyAdmin should get the 
exact row count using SELECT COUNT. If the approximate row count as returned 
by SHOW TABLE STATUS is smaller than this value, SELECT COUNT will be used, 
otherwise the approximate count will be used.
```

Comment: Link down............

Comment: @Pacerier: Better link.

Comment: Ah, [now](http://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/1509/revisions) you made my answer redundant.......

Answer (score 1):

phpMyAdmin will only do an **actual** `select count(*)` if the estimated number of rows are within the set threshold (default is 500k depending on your version):

> [`$cfg['MaxExactCount']`](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_MaxExactCount)
>
> For InnoDB tables, determines for how large tables phpMyAdmin should get the exact row count using `SELECT COUNT`. If the approximate row count as returned by `SHOW TABLE STATUS` is smaller than this value, `SELECT COUNT` will be used, otherwise the approximate count will be used.

Simply set the threshold to a smaller number to avoid pointless `select count(*)`s.